# What is a Self-Rejecting Number™?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

*This puzzle is based off the What is a Word™, What is a Phrase™ and What is a Number™ series started by JLee.*

If a number conforms to a certain rule, I call it a Self-Rejecting Number™. Use the following examples to find the rule:

| Self-Rejecting Numbers™ | Non-Self-Rejecting Numbers™ |
| --- | --- |
| 836 | 638 |
| 7192 | 9172 |
| 7912 | 1972 |
| 13930 | 13931 |
| 17272 | 27171 |
| 570988 | 988570 |
| 999670 | 666970 |
| 1811110 | 1111810 |
| 3123470 | 2432170 |
| 3432170 | 2123470 |
| 5555690 | 5555960 |
| 6035084 | 4805306 |

Here is a CSV:

```
Self-Rejecting Numbers™,Non-Self-Rejecting Numbers™
836,638
7192,9172
7912,1972
13930,13931
17272,27171
570988,988570
999670,666970
1811110,1111810
3123470,2432170
3432170,2123470
5555690,5555960
6035084,4805306
```

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each number can be tested for whether it is a Self-Rejecting Number™ without relying on the other numbers.

These are not the only examples of Self-Rejecting Numbers™, more can be found.

Hint 1 (small):

> It is an open question in mathematics whether any are odd.

Comment: This is my first puzzle on Puzzling SE, so please let me know whether it's a good one! :)

Comment: Any reason why the left list is in order but not the right list?

Comment: @stackreader It's just so the numbers on the left and right bear a resemblance to each other. As in the statement, each number can be tested for whether it is a Self-Rejecting Number™ without relying on any other numbers.

Comment: Are there examples of Self-Rejecting Numbers that are odd?

Comment: @Joe see my hint - if you want one

Comment: IMVHO the puzzle is too easy or too hard, depending on an approach. Lucky me, I found the fast approach, but I'm not going to post the answer as I feel quite ...weird, like cheating ;-)

Comment: @CiaPan What was your approach? I realise now that the puzzle was susceptible to a Google search of the list of numbers.

Comment: @boboquack That's it. Just searched. Used OEIS, not Google though. That's why I felt like cheating – I didn't _solve_ the the problem, rather just _found_ the solution instead. And that was a 'too easy' way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Self-Rejecting Numbers™ are ...

> weird.
>  no. really.  they're [weird](https://oeis.org/A006037).

And they are Self-Rejecting™ because ...

> their definition is such that the sum of their divisors is greater than the number itself, but no subset of those divisors adds exactly to the number itself; that is, no set of their divisors can add up to themselves, so in this way they never match themselves (and thus self-reject).

Comment: I have three questions: How did you get to this answer? Did you think this was a good question? Can you explain the name Self-Rejecting?

Comment: The "small" hint actually is what led me to the solution.  Well, that and this handy [list of unsolved problems in mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics) and a quick search on that page for the word "odd".  Only two things turned up - are there any odd perfect numbers, and are there any odd weird numbers.  Looking at both, it was trivial to find that your list came from the list of weird numbers.

Comment: Should I make more of this type of question? (I have only seen 2 posted, and 1 was deleted)

Comment: Correct in why they are self-rejecting

Comment: In all honesty I think this question devolves to math trivia, and without the hint it probably wouldn't be solvable. Questions like that generally don't make good *puzzles* since they can't really be reasoned out or guessed at in anyone's lifetime. A puzzle should be solvable without knowing its solution.

Comment: Alright, next time I'll try and make it more solvable. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: OEIS can be searched and if you omit the large numbers from the search, you can find the [weird numbers](https://oeis.org/search?q=836+7192+7912+13930+17272&sort=&language=english&go=Search). (You have to suspect that the numebsr are from a sequence in the first place, of course.)

Comment: yeah - I wasn't expecting this to just be an OEIS sequence, though, or I would have started there.

Comment: That's why I didn't include the lowest weird numbers, someone might have been able to find something special about 70

Comment: @boboquack Apparently you're not aware OEIS search machine doesn't need you input the *initial* part of a sequence, and not even an *ordered* or *contiguous* part. See this example: [OEIS 7192 13930 7912](http://oeis.org/search?q=7192+13930+7912).

Comment: @CiaPan Now it fails. However this works: [seq:7192 seq:13930 seq:7912](http://oeis.org/search?q=seq%3A7192+seq%3A13930+seq%3A7912)

Comment: @Scratch---Cat As well as this: ["7192" "13930" "7912"](http://oeis.org/search?q=%227192%22+%2213930%22+%227912%22). Hints: http://oeis.org/hints.html